# SQL Server 2014: Why is Clustered Index Rebuild MUCH faster than initial index creation?

Tags: sql-server, index, index-rebuild

I have a table where rows consist of a few GUID ids and then a huge byte array of data.  There is a partitioned clustered index on this table, which orders data by the GUIDs.

The table is large, containing ~3tb of data, most of which is the byte array of data, which is not a part of the index.  When first creating the index, it took well over a day, but the index rebuild (not reorganize) took under an hour.  **Why did the rebuild go so much quicker?** My understanding is it would have to drop and re-create the clustered index, which would involve it re-writing this large table all over again.

It's might be worth noting that when lookin at size reports for the table, the table itself takes ~3tb but the index is 1gb or less. Also worth noting, the table wasn't partitioned until that initial index create I did previously, while the rebuild was done on an already partitioned table.  Not sure if that makes an impact.

Again, just trying to gain understanding.  Why would my rebuild be so significantly faster than the initial create?

EDIT: It is the **clustered index** I initially created and was re-building. There are no other indexes on this table

Comment: Did you change database models in between to Simple or Bulk Logged or make any other notable changes?  Were you doing one during a very busy period?

Comment: Also just to clarify, is this the clustered index you're rebuilding?  Or a non clustered index? You mentioned clustered but I wasn't clear if this is the one you're actually rebuilding.  Can you share your table structure too?

Comment: "My understanding is it would have to drop and re-create the clustered index". Why would SQL Server need to do that? The clustered index already exists, and importantly for performance, in the desired order since the index definition is not changed.

Comment: You're not accounting for the part where you went from a non-partitioned heap to a partitioned table when creating the clustered index.

Comment: ^Agreed with Sean on this one. Also /* Insert usual disclaimer that rebuilding indexes are a wasteful operation that are typically unnecessary. */

Comment: It can be explained in many ways and more details but as a comment I can say it has much fewer WRITE operation.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 
@AliRazeghi-AWS There were no notable changes between, logging included, and it is a clustered index I'm rebuilding.

Comment: @DanGuzman per microsoft docs: "Rebuilding an index drops and re-creates the index. "   Seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @J.D. in this case there were partitions incorrectly removed, (which is typically how deletion occurs, via partition switching) and query performance was severely degraded.  The rebuild in this situation solved that issue, so it wasn't entirely wasteful!

Comment: @frobot Not sure I fully follow, but the only time I've seen index rebuilds necessary for performance are in poor table designs that don't use clustered indexes (when they should've) therefore storing the data in a Heap that fragments very quickly. If you saw performance gains in a table that's already clustered in a B-Tree, then any gains you had were likely related to the correlative actions that happen as part of the rebuild process such as updated statistics. But you can run such processes separately without the need to do rebuilds, and still reap the benefits of the performance gains.

Comment: @J.D. I assume the performance gains were because it re-created partition boundaries that were incorrectly removed. 

Typically I remove data via partition switching, but there was a bug in my Data Access Service that incorrectly merged some partition boundaries.  There is so much data in each partition, that if 2 partitions get combined, it would destroy the retrieval speeds.

I assume the clustered index rebuild must've restored these partition boundaries, which brought the query speeds back to normal

Comment: @frobot, more precisely, rebuilding the clustered index creates a new index and then drops the old one at completion. The sort order of the old index is leveraged for the rebuild.

Comment: @frobot Partitioning is not meant for DQL performance, especially `SELECT` performance. Rather it's a tool for improved data management. Partitioning is just a linear segregation of the data, think `O(n)`, which doesn't mean much with a lot of data. Indexes, which use B-Trees, are `O(Log(n))` which is literally exponentially better regarding performance. I doubt the combination of two partitions would tank your performance if your table was properly indexed, given that the number of rows you're `SELECT`ing wouldn't change. I've worked with tables in the 10s of billions without partitioning.

Comment: @J.D. for better or for worse, the index in question doesn't contain the partition key, so if the partition boundaries are removed, the index isn't very useful in looking up the data. The partition key is essentially treated as the leading field of the index.


The table wasn't partitioned for retrieval improvements, it was partitioned for insertion improvements.  The db stores results from jobs that produce a ton of data.  The results needs to be stored ASAP for use, it was a lot faster for the table to be partitioned by job.

Any ways I really appreciate your responses, its helpful!

Comment: @frobotb Oh ok, when you said "*would destroy the retrieval speeds*" I thought you meant your `SELECT` queries. I'm still unaware of partitioning helping `INSERT` performance but I'm not an expert enough on using it in that regard to definitively say.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're creating a clustered or a nonclustered index, the operator which does the lion's share of the work appears to be the sort. But when you rebuild the index -- clustered or nonclustered, online or offline -- SQL Server appears to scans the existing index first, which is already sorted.

E.g.

Let's create a nonclustered index on the StackOverflow Users table (after setting IO statistics on):

```sql
USE [StackOverflow] ;
GO
SET STATISTICS IO ON ;
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Users_Reputation_DESC_Location_DisplayName]
    ON dbo.Users
    ( [Reputation] DESC, [Location] ASC, [DisplayName] ASC ) ;
GO
```

This operation reads **141572** pages:

[image]

And the execution plan looks like this:

[image]

PasteThePlan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syzxzzufo

Note the Clustered Index Scan (i.e. scanning the whole table) and the Sort operators.

Now let's rebuild the index offline:

```sql
USE [StackOverflow] ;
GO
SET STATISTICS IO ON ;
GO
ALTER INDEX [IX_Users_Reputation_DESC_Location_DisplayName]
    ON dbo.Users
    REBUILD 
    WITH ( SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF ) ;
GO
```

This operation only reads **53360** pages -- nearly a third of the pages read when creating the the index:

[image]

With this execution plan looking like:

[image]

PasteThePlan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryg2GfdMi

Note that this time, SQL Server is only scanning the existing nonclustered index, and not the clustered one again. Plus now now we have no Sort operator chewing up CPU time.

The same is true for rebuilding  of a clustered index. But while this operation scans the existing clustered index first, so the page reads are on parr with creating the clustered index, it still doesn't need to re-sort the data.

So it looks like an index rebuild is actually doing less work than an index create.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Charlieface. Done.

Comment: This was helpful and very informative, thank you!